# CSS Background Colour and Image Conflicting

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I have a piece of CSS that I've used a number of times that combines a background image and a background colour and, to this point, I've not had a problem with it. However, in this instance, I've got a weird issue with mobile browsers where it's shrinking the background image by 1px all the way around, revealing the background colour where I don't want it to be seen!

The CSS:

```
.navlink {
background-color: #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
height: 20px;
width: 200px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
background-image: url(images/navarrowblank.gif);
background-position: top right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

It doesn't matter what HTML element the class is applied to. It also doesn't matter if I'm using an iOS device or an Android device (but if I try the same code in any desktop browser [and it's been checked in all the obvious ones!], I don't see any issues at all).

I have already tried background-size and setting the object's border to 0 - neither of which resolved the issue.

The image itself is 24px by 25px but appears to be displaying at 18px by 23px.

Any suggestions, or should I just bite the bullet and create the whole background as an image and lose the background colour?

JSFiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/frustratedwithdotnet/a64VP/2/ (note: red border removed)

Comment: could you create a fiddle with your issue please http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Have you tried creating an other class with the background-image instead of putting it all in one class?

Comment: have you tried `background-size: cover;`

Comment: @web-tiki - if the suggestions I've already been given don't solve my problem, I'll set something up

Comment: @joeriSmits - no I haven't, but I'll give that a try

Comment: @sam - nope, didn't try that; I just tried setting the background size to be the size of the image; will give that a try

Comment: @Sam - tried that and that just makes the background image expand out to cover the whole element, which I specifically don't want!

Comment: @web-tiki http://jsfiddle.net/frustratedwithdotnet/a64VP/

Comment: Ihave tried your fiddle on an android device and I don't see the issue... no background-color around the background image. The image is behaving like it should, it is cropped to the height of the container. Is your aim to resize the image to the size of the container?

Comment: I hadn't - was doing about 30 things at once and made the stupid mistake of assuming that since it had misbehaved every other time I used that code in this format it would misbehave appropriately here. Excuse me, I have a brickwall my head would like to make contact with! (I'll see if I can get it replicating the problem - sorry!)

Comment: Okay. The fiddle version works (ie behaves as it should) in Android, but the website that triggered this still doesn't. And the fiddle *doesn't* work in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After four days of hair-tugging, and with no explanations available as to why code that I've used dozens of times in other places should suddenly go doolally, I've solved it by making the background image the full width of the container (instead of just 24px by 25px) and filling it black instead of relying on the background colour to do that (leaving the right hand end white).

Not happy with that solution, but absent anything else it's the best I've got for now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can not specify a background color and image on the same level. The hierarchy pretty much says that images take priority over colors. To get the effect you are looking for, you'll need to wrap the element in a div and style it with your background color.

So, you'll be looking at something like:

```
.wrap { background: #000; }
.nav-link { background: url(images/navarrowblank.gif) top left no-repeat; }

<div class="wrap"><div class="nav-link">Lorem Ipsum</div></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give this a try (I'm willing to try anything!) but your answer doesn't make sense, given my problem is the background colour showing up around the background image and the image being shown smaller than it is. That doesn't seem like the image is taking priority to me!

Comment: I've now tried this and nope; this does not solve my problem. I end up with either white text on a white background, or the black background only around the words, not extending to the full width of my element (depending on which way around I arrange the code).